# How to set up React and Redux project without npm (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have seen lot of videos and posts configuring project with npm (Node.js). I already have .Net server where I want to use React.JS and Redux.

I could set it up for React by adding following JS file downloaded.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/src/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/src/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/src/browser.min.js"></script>
```

But how to include Redux in my application to use React with Redux?

Comment: Here you are my dude: http://jamesknelson.com/learn-raw-react-no-jsx-flux-es6-webpack/